Issue with Redirecting the user to the Google Wallet installation page
I'm trying to add a boarding pass to Google Wallet using com.google.android.gms:play-services-pay API , but I'm encountering an issue. The user doesn't have Google Wallet installed and hasn't synced a Google account. How can I handle this scenario? Also OnActivityResult callback is not helpful here.
